# INSERT INTO SELECT * FROM, while converting a data type into a foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I currently work for a company that services generators, and we've recently received a huge list of about 6000 new pieces of equipment, I've been asked to see if I can write a script to import the data into our web application's database, but I am still VERY new to the coding side of IT.

My current solution is to use an INSERT INTO query to pull the data into the production database, however my goal is to make this script as user friendly as possible, so they can use it even if I happen to move elsewhere.

With that being said, my question would be how do I write a query to turn an "Asset Type" field (i.e. Generator, ATS) into a foreign key associated with that type (1001, 1002) and then insert it into the database? Is this possible, or will we have to convert the equipment into fks before running the script?

I did see a similar question about altering data, but unless I'm just misunderstanding the answer, that didn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Depends on how your database structure looks. Please provide some more details about the table you're trying to insert, that asset type table holding those types & the raw data you're given.

Comment: The asset type table in the target database is very simple. Most of the columns are NULL values, the only two important columns being the PK (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004) and the actual asset type (Generator, ATS, Fire Pump, etc.). The table I'm inserting consists of data from multiple interconnected tables on the target db, such as Customers, Sites, and Equipment. The data I have to import is Customer Name (Customers), Site Number, Address, State (site), Tag Number, Equip Type, Serial, KW Size, Model Number, and Manufacturer. Type and Manufacturer are fks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend on top of using a staging table as JohnHC has suggested but also using an SSIS package that they can then in the future just create a csv file, put it in a specific folder, and then a job that checks for the file every 15 minutes (or whatever you choose) will run the package when it finds anything with the specific name and format in that folder. Would make it so they dont even need to look at code but just need to populate a CSV file.

Comment: That does sound very nice. I'll need to look into that, thank you.

Comment: to run a package/job when a file lands in a folder:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+%28SSIS%29/90571/

to make an SSIS package to load data into a table from a csv file:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

Use a staging table...

```
create table Stage1 (AssetId INT identity(1000,1) primary key, AssetInfo varchar(20), OtherFields...);

insert into Stage1 (AssetInfo, OtherFields)
select distinct AssetInfo, OtherFields
from ExistingAssetTable
;
```

Then you can use the now-generated keys to populate your other table

Comment: I wasn't expecting an answer so quickly, that's pretty awesome. I can't say I fully understand what each bit of the code does, but that won't be an issue to learn. As for what the snippet itself does, it'd be importing the data into that table, and it would assign the data the appropriate keys, then gets imported into the target table?

Comment: This creates a staging table (a table where you park the data, make it fit the new format before you use it) and then fills it. Make sure to change field names and data types (but not the AssetId field).

From here, you can use a `insert into [existingtable] sselect [fields] from Stage1` statement

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. I just import it into that table and then format it myself, right? Could I ask what the advantage is in doing this rather than formatting it before the import? I know I saw someone in another thread about this saying it had to do with checking for errors and the like. Is that correct?  Sorry for asking so many questions.